# LaTeX not rendering for Stack Exchange on Chrome

Tags: bug, mathjax

First of all, the problem is with all Stack Exchange communities on Chrome only. Everything was working fine until I cleared my cache of every website in Chrome. Since then LaTeX is not being rendered in my Chrome browser while it is rendered in Firefox.

Here is the snapshot of chrome console:

[image]

Comment: This is purely a mathjax/javascript question so does not involve tex at all and so is off topic here, you may be best to ask on the main stackexchange meta since it seems to be the winter hats code.

Comment: Try browsing the site without https:// (just http://) and see if it helps. Also, disable HTTPS Everywhere if you got it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the "winter hats" error is unrelated, it's a different error in different file.

Comment: @ShadowWizard ah yes, perhaps you are right but anyway it's still a javascript mathjax config issue so an issue for meta stackexchange and/or the mathjax forum not related to tex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle true, though bugs can be reported on any meta site. No harm done.

Comment: The first error shown in your screen shot suggests that the MathJax configuration files was not fully loaded (or was terminated part way through). That is likely the cause of the other MathJax-related errors that you are seeing. Try clearing the cache again and restart the browser. Restarting the browser is important in Chrome, so don't neglect that. Clearning the cache is not enough, in general.

Comment: Yes @DavideCervone, clearing the cache didn't work but restarting the browser worked fine. Still I want to know why did this problem happen so that I can avoid this in future ?

Comment: You probably will never know for sure.  It looks like a file failed to load completely, and that could be because of a timeout on the network, or losing your network connection, or something happening on the server sending it, or any number of things.  Most of them are outside your control anyway, and not something you will be able to prevent.  This is what we live with in our age of complex technological interactions.